# finding set of lines before specified word

Tags: python, data-science

So i've got data like this:
header
char[data,data,data,data]

char[data,data,data]

char[data,data,data]

char[data,data,data]

word1

header

char[data,data,data]

char[data,data,data]

char[data,data,data]

word2

I want to check in turn whether the data type is marked with word1 or word 2 and perform operations on the data depending on it. How can I check if it's word1 or word 2?

Comment: I would iterate over the rows appending lines to a list with an `if line in ['word1',' word2']` and then do some conditional stuff on the content of the list

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  You seem to need to work through tutorials on several basic language features.

Answer (score 1):

Standard procedure of parsing files in python would be iterating over the lines, and in your case, doing something to the content conditional on a lines content

```
temp = []
for line in text:
    if line in ['word1', 'word2']:
        do soemthing with temp
        temp = []
    else:
        temp.append(line)
```